# Connecting from rails to an external azure database to import data

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, azure

Hello Stackoverflow members,

I need to import data from an external database which is an azure database. And i am getting the following error:  TinyTds::Error: USE statement is not supported to switch between databases. Use a new connection to connect to a different database.

```
class Exact


require 'tiny_tds'


def connect

dbadmin = ""
password = "!"
server = ""
database = "" 
a =  true


client=TinyTds::Client.new(:username=>'', :password=> password, :dataserver=> server , :port=>1433, :database=>database, :azure=> 'true') 

    puts "connecting"
    results = client.execute("select * from table")
    puts "results opgehaald"
        puts results.first


    client.close
    puts "client is closed"

end 



end
```

I think i need to open a new connection to connect to the database but i am having problems figuring this out. Could anyone point me in the right direction or assist me with the problems i am having.

Kind regards,

Yoeri Huitema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the issue as described in this thread: https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds/issues/249

client=TinyTds::Client.new(:username=>'', :password=> password, :dataserver=> server , :port=>1433, :database=>database, :azure=> 'true')

should have been

client=TinyTds::Client.new(:username=>'', :password=> password, :dataserver=> server , :port=>1433, :database=>database, :azure=> **TRUE**)

Comment: Thanks man! It took me ages to get this working and it was this missing `azure: true`